# How to speed up an iTunes Connect build that is stuck processing?

Tags: ios, build, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload a very important new version to the App Store.

Unfortunately, my builds are stuck processing for 24 hours now and the support tells me to wait. The build size is just 15 MB.

What can I do? Are you experiencing problems like that as well?

Comment: @Rashwan: there is no need to edit posts to merely add bold formatting, especially when there is no typographical justification for such an edit. The fashion for emboldening random words here does not make things more readable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if Apple are taking a long time to process your build, that's not something anyone here can help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally when this happens to me it´s because of the internet connections firewall. Try to change network (I changed to my shared internet through my phone) and see if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not yet but if i dump into this problem then probably there's no way except going [Resources & Help](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/overview) in ITunes connect.We have to always touch with apple [Contact Us](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/jumpTo?page=contactUs) it's only solution as i thought.

Comment: tried that but they couldn't help me... changed to another version number and worked perfectly then, idk what the problem was